# How to check whole number in vc++?

Tags: visual-c++

```
UINT itemLength = strValue.length();
        bRet = ( ( itemLength > maxLength ) || ( itemLength < minLength ) ) ? VARIANT_FALSE : VARIANT_TRUE;
```

This code is being used for Length validation.

I want to validate number:

For Ex:

> min value = 0, Max value =10, original value = 5

In this condition i want to check only whole number.

For Ex, I want to display following:

> Input  -> Output
>
> 5    -> True
>
> 5.1   -> False i want to display.

Answer (score 1):

assuming f as precision number try this

```
if (f % (int)f > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("is not whole number");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("is whole number");
    }
```